# Devise AbstractController::ActionNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a problem with the Devise. My application is new and only has standard code found on : http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise?view=asciicast

Everything is the exactly the same, but after my devise sing up, it sends me to the : ocalhost:3000/users.user with this error showing.

Edit:

I didn't mess around with any of the functions. Here is my rake routes:

```
   new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)      {:action=>"new",     :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
   user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
   destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
   password POST   /users/password(.:format)         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
   new_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
   edit_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
   PUT    /users/password(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
   registration POST   /users(.:format)                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   edit_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   PUT    /users(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   DELETE /users(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
   new_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
   GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     {:action=>"show",:controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
   root        /      {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
```

Comment: Unknown action

AbstractController::ActionNotFound

Comment: It sounds like you have some path problem. Have you overwritten the after_sign_up_path_for(resource) method? Have you modified the devise views? Can you execute ```rake routes``` in your terminal and show us the devise specific paths

Comment: For an up-to-date example of a simple Rails application using Devise, there's the [rails-devise](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise/) example application from the RailsApps project. I've also written a [Rails Devise Tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-devise/) that may be helpful.

Comment: I didn't mess around with any of the functions. Here is my rake routes:

Comment: @DanielKehoe Thank you, but I would rather deal with this problem head on, so I can get to the bottom of this stuff.

Comment: It was actually problem in the devise gem version. Since I am using rails 3.1.12, I had to install a couple of versions of devise. The one that worked was 1.4.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually problem in the devise gem version. Since I am using rails 3.1.12, I had to install a couple of versions of devise. The one that worked was 1.4.7.